# Query string in CKEditor upload PHP script call get stripped

Tags: php, upload, ckeditor

I was using the 4.7.3 version of CKEditor in a site I'm developing and now I decided to upgrade it to the latest version, that is, 4.9. It seems that the image upload feature has changed a bit because now I have to add the `filebrowser` plugin to the `config.extraPlugins` setting so the `CKEditorFuncNum` var in the upload script query string is correctly populated:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" dir="ltr" action="/xxxx/uploader.php?CKEditor=editor1&amp;CKEditorFuncNum=1&amp;langCode=en" lang="en">
```

Also, when I click the "Send it to the Server" to upload an image, the query GET parameters in the form get mysteriously stripped, so the upload script cannot get the value of the `CKEditorFuncNum` var and breaks:

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error. 
Object { responseText: "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(, 'http://example.com/uploads/file_uploaded.jpg', '');</script>"
```

Is anyone in the same situation? Is there anything I'm missing? I can go back to the 4.7.3 version of CKEditor, but I'd like not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `config.filebrowserUploadMethod` setting is set to 'xhr' by default in 4.9. To make the uploads work as before I had to set it to 'form'.

Comment: Great answer. This has me stumped for a few hours, as CKEditorFuncNum wasn't getting sent to my server method at all after I upgraded. Thanks!